# django rest framework: ordering not working properly

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model with ForeignField named typeofingredient.

If i try the following serializer class

```
class IngredientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'
```

and then I try  http://localhost:8000/api/ingredients/?ordering=typeofingredient

The results are all sorted w.r.t to the id of typeofingredient.

Later i waned to show the name field of typeofingredient instead of id in api. SO i changed the serializer class to below:

```
class IngredientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    typeofingredient = ReadOnlyField(source='typeofingredient.name')
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'
```

and then I try  http://localhost:8000/api/ingredients/?ordering=typeofingredient, It does not order the results at all.

how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1005 
and
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5533

So i have update my djangrestframework:

```
$ pip install djangorestframework -U
Collecting djangorestframework
  Downloading djangorestframework-3.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 447kB/s 
Installing collected packages: djangorestframework
  Found existing installation: djangorestframework 3.3.3
    Uninstalling djangorestframework-3.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled djangorestframework-3.3.3
Successfully installed djangorestframework-3.7.3
```

Then everything worked well

```
class IngredientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    typeofingredient = ReadOnlyField(source='typeofingredient.name',default=None)
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__
```

http://localhost:8000/api/ingredients/?ordering=-typeofingredient and 
http://localhost:8000/api/ingredients/?ordering=typeofingredient

works well
'